# Figuring out a way to reduce credit card spend due to memorizing the card number

Tags: credit-card, spending

I have been fairly good at controlling my credit card spend, but occasionally I spend more than I intend (online). I am not in any kind of debt, and I come out positive at the end of the month, but I could come out *more* positive if I figure out a way to solve this problem.

I started out by burying my credit card in the back of a safe and being lazy this worked fantastically for a while. It reduced my spend considerably. After moving a year ago or so I had to put in/read out my credit card so many times I committed it to memory. *This is bad*.

Now, the block that hiding the credit card had no longer exists. It saves me from using it in the real world, but online I have a habit of buying things I want...regardless of if I need them. Naturally, this can be solved by being cognizant of what I am spending on - but I make enough money that an extra $500 or so dollars barely dents my take home. There just isn't enough pain and suffering there in the moment of "can I afford this?".

I have thought of different solutions - the main one being to just lock my credit card. However, this prevents me from making bill payments for home bills from companies that haven't moved into the 21st century and still require individual invoices per month. This didn't seem sustainable. Further, a lot of companies don't mark their transactions as "recurring".

The second solution was to change my credit card number. This again causes even more problems because I have probably 10 companies altogether I run bills through my credit card.

The third was to just switch to using my debit card. This presents a security risk dealing with necessary online things (bill pay). Moreover, I'd probably end up committing that to memory by accident as well.

Is there any other options? Hypnosis to forget the card number? Head injury? It has become a problem to me and despite my best efforts to stop I can almost robotically enter the number. It's rather frustrating.

I understand this is a strange question...but it's the only place I have more spending than I should I and I would *sure* like to see even half of the money I usually spend a month on my credit card back.

Comment: This would seem to be better suited for psychology or something similar.  It's not really a financial question, but would apply to breaking any habit.

Comment: I really appreciate the downvotes. Really drives home the purpose of this community.

Comment: Well, @JohnA. , this question is _not_ the purpose of this community. And you are supposed to read about the purpose before you post.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about psychology

Comment: @John A.: Yes, if you wanted a Personal Finance answer to your question, it's "Well, just don't buy stuff on line".  How you can go about doing that is not something most of us have any experience with, because we either never started, or can just stop when we want.  So you want to look for answers on psychology sites, sites dealing with addictions, and similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Suggestion is to get a second credit card. Since you evidently have a problem prioritizing your credit card spending, you can alternatively prioritize the card you use online. All you have to do is load the new card with just about enough money you would like to spend online.

In addition, take out some free time to master the new card number - don't let it come to you by habitual usage. Why? Because you might habitually forget carrying the new card along with you.

In general, curbing this kind of spending habit requires you become conscious and intentional about every step you take in making financial decisions, even if it's a trivial and unnecessary one. For instance, acting surprised when you receive a message or notification that you are about to reach your credit card limit on your new card and smiling to yourself. I bet you aren't use to that :)

Answer (score 1):

> The third was to just switch to using my debit card.

This is what I did.

> This presents a security risk dealing with necessary online things (bill pay).

Yeah, but less than you'd think.  If you're really worried about it, open up a separate checking account, use that debit card, and only transfer money to it when necessary for normal bills.

> Moreover, I'd probably end up committing that to memory by accident as well.

That doesn't matter, since you'd only have enough in the account for required bills.

**Most importantly**, though, is that you must really really, **Want** to change your behavior.